# Comma category: completeness

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

Let $C$ be a category and $c\in C$ an object.
What are the necessary and sufficient conditions for the comma category $$(c\downarrow C)$$ to be (co)complete ?

Comment: The nlab has a short paragraph on the (co)completeness of comma categories. See [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/comma+category#completeness_and_cocompleteness)

Comment: Also, what you wrote down is often called a co-slice category and is a special case of a general comma category $(f \downarrow g)$ where $f: A \rightarrow B$ $g: C \rightarrow B$. It is obtained by setting $A = \{\ast\}$, $B = C$ and $f(\ast) = c \in C$ and $g = \text{id}_C$.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3183570/completeness-of-over-category-slice/3183682#3183682) of me explains when the slice $\mathcal{C} \downarrow C$ is complete. So dually that statement explains when $C \downarrow \mathcal{C}$ is cocomplete.